# Extension of the question "Python logging multiple files using the same logger"

Tags: python, logging, config

This is extension of this [query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15199816/python-logging-multiple-files-using-the-same-logger).

The bug I found with the config file is by using the logger, at any point of time both `ws_in_.log` and `ws_out_.log` files are getting created even though they are under different handlers and meant for different processes. I mean, if I run `IN` process then respective `IN` logs are getting logged in `ws_in.log` file. But along with that an empty `ws_out.log` file is also getting created.

So is there any way of restricting the creation of log file for respective process.please help.

Thanks & Regards Pragyan

```
[loggers]
keys=root, ws_in_log, ws_out_log

[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler, ws_in_hand, ws_out_hand

[formatters]
keys=generic_form

[loggers]
keys=root, ws_in_log, ws_out_log

[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler, ws_in_hand, ws_out_hand

[formatters]
keys=generic_form

[logger_root]
handlers=consoleHandler
level=NOTSET

[logger_ws_in_log]
level=NOTSET
handlers=ws_in_hand
qualname=ws_in_log

[logger_ws_out_log]
level=NOTSET
handlers=ws_out_hand
qualname=ws_out_log

[handler_ws_in_hand]
class=logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler
level=NOTSET
formatter=generic_form
args=('/path/ws_in_.log', 'h', 1, 0, None, False, True)

[handler_ws_out_hand]
class=logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler
level=NOTSET
formatter=generic_form
args=('/path/em/ws_out_.log', 'h', 1, 0, None, False, True)

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=generic_form
args=(sys.stdout,)

[formatter_generic_form]
format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
class=
```

I am using the above config file by the scrpit IN.py,

```
import logging.config

logging.config.fileConfig('x.ini')
logger=logging.getLogger('ws_in_log')
class Car(object):
    def __init__(self,brand,model,color):
        self.brand = brand
        self.model = model
        self.color = color

    def drive(self):
        self.condition = 'Used'
        print("in drive")
def drive(msg):
    logger.debug("in script function")
    logger.debug(msg)

Expected : only "ws_in_.log" file shoud be created if "IN" script get called.
Actual: Both "ws_in_.log" and "ws_out_.log" files are getting created if only "IN" script get called.
```

Comment: Linked question is deleted. Please edit it out. Questions should stand on their own.

Comment: updated the link of the previous query. However, the information i have given is enough to mention the problem.

Comment: please also add the code how you instantiate and use the loggers

Comment: @blues, added the code where i am passing the key of logger

Answer (score 0):

The one way to fix this is to replace logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler with a version that only opens or creates the file when it receives a message to log to the file.

Another is to just accept the creation of the empty file.

The implementation of logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler creates the log file if it does not exist when its instance is created.

Comment: Its not only about "logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler" . If two handlers are of same type then the log file is created unwanted.  Until unless the type handlers are different it works fine. So is there any way to restrict other handlers based on the keys or logger name?